# Breeze: $expand not working with breeze/web api2

Tags: breeze

We migrated to webapi 2 and $expand is not working anymore on collections. We are using NHibernate with breeze 1.4.7.

When we try to expand a collection, it simply returns an empty array. The odd part is that the generated sql follows the usage of the expand keyword.

The same code is working as expected with web api v1

Is it a bug in the web api 2 version of breeze?

Comment: We have heard that our NH project may have to be recompiled for Web API2. The man behind it is on vacation until the end of the month. I'm sorry I don't know what more I can tell you.

Comment: Actually, it has been recompiled but is still under testing. The preliminary version is available on GitHub in the Breeze\Breeze.ContextProvider.NH subdir.

Comment: Ok thank you but during my tests I already downloaded the latest source and compiled it. So the issue still exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. MS changed some of the OData handling in WebApi 2, and our NH support didn't change with it.

The fix is in 1.4.8 (expected to be out tomorrow). We apologize for the inconvenience.